# Why is Eventarc trigger not working in Firebase?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, event-arc

In Firebase I have installed extension `Resize Images` which claims to send an event upon completion: `firebase.extensions.storage-resize-images.v1.complete`

I have created a function trigger to handle this event:

```
exports.onimageresized2 = onCustomEventPublished(
  {
    eventType: 'firebase.extensions.storage-resize-images.v1.complete',
    channel: 'projects/perfect-stroke-project/locations/europe-west4/channels/firebase',
    region: 'europe-west4',
  },
  async (event: unknown) => {
    const item = {
      name: 'Hello',
    };
    const swingRequestDocRef = await firestore.collection('tool_types').add(item);

    console.log(swingRequestDocRef.id);

    console.log('it works!', JSON.stringify(event));
    info([{ message: 'Received image resize completed event', event: event }]);
    write({ message: 'received', severity: 'WARNING' });
  },
);
```

### To clarify regional settings

My firebase settings show: `eur3 (europe-west)`

My extension is set to: `europe-west3`

My extension is set to send Events to channel in `europe-west4`

I am expecting that the even will trigger the handling and thus a) show logs, b) create item in Firestore. However, neither of those happens. I try to use `Logs Explorer` to search for any of the logs I have in my event handler, but none exist. In the meantime, I can confirm that extension is working and files get created, and I can see the logs for that extension.

How can I figure out what is wrong with the event and event handler?

Answer (score 2):

I suspected there is something to do with the regions and it indeed seems so.

There is only 1 region that exists as an option on all items - `firebase`, the `extensions`, the `functions`, `eventarc` and the region is `us-central1`

So I created a new firebase, migrated the data, set everything to this one region and it worked.

I wish there was an error somewhere to let me know that instead of having to experiment and lose a few days, but I wasn't able to find out a meaningful debugging process.